# Changing the props/state of dynamically generated child component from the data the parent receives

Tags: reactjs

The main idea is that if there are dynamically generated components , how can their props/or state be changed from the parent component. how can the parent know which child component to update.

can i somehow tell the parent component to set the state and pass the value to the correct child component, rather then changing all the child components, the child components will all be similar(clones but each can have different props , state)

this is my basic code and i want to change the state of only 1 span rather then both, i want to apply that idea to components.

```
class MainApp  extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
 super(props)

this.ChangeText= this.ChangeText.bind(this)
 this.state={
   text: "hi"
 }
}

ChangeText(e){
this.setState ({
  text: "hellow"
  })
 }




 render() {
    return (
  <div>
      <button onClick={this.ChangeText}>Click </button>
      <span>{this.state.text}</span>
      <span>{this.state.text}</span>
  </div>
    );
  }
 }
```

Comment: You need to give the spans different states if you want to affect individual spans only.

Comment: if i dont know how many spans there will be ? then how can i give them different states?

Comment: Use an index. Loop through the dynamic data from parent and assign it to the state using array index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to identify each span somehow, it could be based on an index (ie. text1, text2, text3, and so on...) then manage each one separately in the state, the you will have something like:

```
this.setState({
  text1: "hello",
  text2: "how are",
  text3: "you doing?"
});
```

And in your render method:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{this.state.text1}</span>
      <span>{this.state.text2}</span>
      <span>{this.state.text3}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

That same behavior can be used for components, as React will re-render and pass the updated props to any component using the part of the state that you update.